# Is there a way to seed a key with a value of an array of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seeding

I'm trying to seed some data using an external trivia API.

Here's what I have in my seeds.rb file where HTTParty is a gem that parses JSON into a ruby hash:

```
response = HTTParty.get("THE-API-SITE")
response.each do |trivia|
    triviaHash = {
        category: trivia["category"],
        answer: trivia["correctAnswer"],
        incorrect: trivia["incorrectAnswers"],
        question: trivia["question"],
    }
    Trivia.find_or_create_by(triviaHash)
end
```

And here's my schema:

```
create_table "trivia", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "category"
    t.string "answer"
    t.string "incorrect"
    t.string "question"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "ids"
  end
```

Everything works except for the "incorrect" key which should have a value of an array of strings of incorrect answers, but when I seed my data, I get a string of the array of incorrect answers.

What I want:

```
incorrect: ["Deep Purple", "Feeder", "Uriah Heep"],
```

What I'm getting:

```
incorrect: "["Deep Purple", "Feeder", "Uriah Heep"]",
```

I'm not sure how to get what I want or if it's even possible the way I'm going about it.

Comment: Your array is stored as a string because the data type of the column in the database is string. You might want to use [the array data type](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array) instead.

Comment: Apparently I was using SQLite and not postgresql which would've helped from the get-go knowing that there was an array data type. I thank all of you who answered my question, I appreciate you guys truly.

Answer (score 0):

Since your column `incorrect` is of type string, so the data stored in DB will also be a string value.

If your DB supports array data type then you can use that or else I would suggest you to use this in your model.

```
serialize :incorrect, Array
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your migration field for `incorrect` field, from:

```
t.string "incorrect"
```

to:

```
t.text :incorrect, array: true, default: []
```

Also I suggest you to use symbols instead of strings for column names and use `t.timestamps` that generates `created_at` and `updated_at` for you